# Selenium Learning step by step

Tags: selenium, selenium-builder

I am new to selenium web testing. Could you tell me how to learn it step by step, and what  the technologies are that I need to study?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you download [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Se Builder](http://www.sebuilder.com/), which are user interfaces for recording Selenium tests in-browser. Both let you record and then export tests to a bunch of different languages.

One important thing to note is that there's two Seleniums: original Selenium 1, where tests are comprised of a list of steps to execute in order, and Selenium 2 / Webdriver, which is an API for programming tests.

(Full disclosure: I'm the main developer on Se Builder, so I'm totally biased towards it. I do think it's probably less intimidating for a newcomer, but Selenium IDE is as of time of writing the more established and standard IDE. :) )

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED: Additional resources listed below**

The record and playback tools Zarkonnen called out are good starts. You also need to understand the fundamentals of Selenium itself. There's good information on writing tests in code on [Selenium HQ's documentation pages](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html).

Three things I think important to get correct from the start:

- [Learn about locators on pages](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#locating-ui-elements-webelements), learn how to store them in one location (read up on the Page Object Pattern and be careful about record/playback tools which may not help you in that approach)
- Learn how to deal with dynamic content (AJAX) with [implicit and explicit waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits)
- Learn about modular tests. Write small, reusable components.

If you're working in Ruby then I'd really recommend having a look at [Cheezy's page_object gem](http://www.cheezyworld.com/2011/07/29/introducing-page-object-gem/).

Also, have a look at [the various intro pages](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) on the Google WebDriver project page.

Update: You should also consider having a look at Dave Haeffner's [Elemental Selenium](http://elementalselenium.com/) and his [Selenium Guidebook](https://seleniumguidebook.com/). Both are great resources for real-world stuff people struggle with, not facile, shallow examples.